# Get skin color contour region in android using opencv

Tags: opencv, contour, android, hsv

The following is the code that I run to find the face region

```
 private void detectRegion() {

    //get the image from gallery and change it into bitmap
    Bitmap bmpTemp = originalImg.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpTemp, mRgbMat);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgbMat, mHsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, channelCount);

    Scalar lowerThreshold = new Scalar(0, 0.23 * 255, 50); // Blue color – lower hsv values
    Scalar upperThreshold = new Scalar(50, 0.68 * 255, 255); // Blue color – higher hsv values
    Core.inRange(mHsvMat, lowerThreshold, upperThreshold, mMaskMat);
    Imgproc.dilate(mMaskMat, mDilatedMat, new Mat());

    Imgproc.findContours(mMaskMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Imgproc.drawContours(mRgbMat, contours,counter, colorGreen, iLineThickness);
    Log.d(TAG + " contours " , contours.get(counter).toString());

    // convert to bitmap:
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mHsvMat.cols(), mHsvMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgbMat, bm);

    // find the imageview and draw it!
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

However, I get so many regions that I did't want.
This is my desired region ( the green one) that I find manually. I add the value when I click the button and draw different region when I press the button.

[image]

this is the message of show in logcat.

> 02-16 00:11:46.413 14234-14234/fyp.hkust.facet D/ColorizeFaceActivity contours: Mat [ 932*1*CV_32SC2, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xffffffff96aa78f8, dataAddr=0xffffffff96a57010 ]

I also tried to draw them all but there are so many extra regions that I don't want.

```
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
        if (contours.size() > 100)  // Minimum size allowed for consideration
        {
            Imgproc.drawContours(mRgbMat, contours, contourIdx, colorGreen, iLineThickness);
            Log.d(TAG + " contours " , contours.get(contourIdx).toString());
        }
    }
```

This is the whole result
[image]

How can I classify them to get the face region and also I need to extract the hsv value in that region. How can I do that? Please give me some help. Thank you very much.